# Flutter: Como evitar que sqflite actualice la base de datos local en una actualización en la tienda?

Tags: flutter

Quiero saber como evitar que cuando el usuario actualice la aplicación, sea automaticamente o cuando la app le pida actualizar, pierda registros en la base de datos que aun no se han sincronizado.

Estoy usando sqflite y al momento de que se actualiza la aplicación y el usuario tenia datos localmente, estos datos se pierden cuando se realizan cambios en la estructura de la base de datos.

Adjunto el código que tengo:

```
class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
  Database _database;

  Future<Database> getDatabase() async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    _database = await initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
    final String databasePath = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'my_database.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      databasePath,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {

        await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE module (id TEXT, name TEXT, code TEXT, campusId TEXT)',
        );
      },

      onUpgrade: (Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
        if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
          await db.execute(
            'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS module',
          );

          await db.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE module (id TEXT, name TEXT, code TEXT, campusId TEXT, otherFile TEXT)',
          );
        }
      },
      version: 81,
    );
  }
}
```

Como quiero agregar un nuevo campo a la tabla, tengo que incrementar la version, y al incrementarla se borra la tabla con la estructura anterior y se crea con los nuevos campos. Pero no quiero perder los datos que el usuario tenia hasta que los sincronice.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que modifiques algún campo de la base de datos, esta debe reconstruirse con los nuevos parámetros que has ingresado, por eso se te pierden los datos.

Lo mas recomendable es hacer un muy buen análisis de los campos de tu base de datos antes de hacer el despliegue de producción en las tiendas.

Ahora lo otro que puedes hacer, es generar un método de copias de seguridad exportando tu base de datos a un archivo plano, luego después de la actualización el usuario tendría que importar ese archivo para volver a tener sus datos. No es la opción mas intuitiva pero es la única si pretendes realizar cambios continuos en la estructura de la base de datos.

Como ultima opción podrías usar una base de datos online NO-SQL como Firestore. De ese modo puedes ir agregando los campos que desees sin comprometer los datos del cliente.

Comment: La implementación que hice para este caso, es verificar si existen datos creados localmente, agregando un nuevo atributo a la tabla, y asi contar cuantos de estos fueron creados sin conexión, para que solo se actualice la tabla cuando ya no existan datos pendientes de sincronizar.